# context_switch and system call virtualization

Tags: linux, kernel, scheduling

When the kernel is executing a context_switch(), i.e. when it is in that function, is it possible that some other task makes a system call? As far as I understand, as the processor state is being swapped, no other code can actually execute until the context_switch completes. Is this understanding correct?

background: Basically, I want to swap system call tables on context switches. I have 2 versions of the syscall vector, with one of them containing addresses of modified sys call code. When a "process of interest" is scheduled in, I will update the sys_call_table pointer to point to the new one. and then swap it out when the process of interest is swapped out.

I'm new to kernel dev, so feedback on my approach is also welcome. 
PS: I know about ptrace() and it doesn't suit my needs. Too many context switches involved in virtualizing syscalls UML style.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may be thinking about it wrong. Even if the kernel doesn't allow syscalls from other tasks while context_switch is executing, that is only likely to extend as far as the currently executing processor. The other processors can still be executing syscalls while one core is context switching.